# How can I find out which Atom package changes my files permissions to executable?

Tags: elixir, atom-editor, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I use Atom as my project's code editor and it keeps changing my files' permissions on saving. Specifically, it adds to them execute permission.

It's Phoenix-Elixir web project, Atom is running on Windows, but I do my gitting and run my local server using WSL.

[On saving a file (test.exs) the execute permission is added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArTPO.png)

I checked Atom settings and, separately, the installed Community Atom Packages' settings, but didn't find something that seems to affect permissions.

Community Packages installed on my Atom: *atom-beautify, atom-elixir, atom-elixir-formatter, language-elixir*

Comment: it might be some workaround for compatibility, I wouldn't care much as long as it works.

Comment: I wonder if it's really a rogue Atom package. Do you by any chance use some sort of file synchronization software or are the files on a network mounted drive? Searching the web shows many strange file attribute related errors when working with any of the above, also in conjunction with WSL.

Comment: The files are located on my local machine. No file synchronization and no network mounted drive. 
The files are in git repository though and on locally mounted drive (as WSL regards Windows drives as mounted, e.g. C:\ is /mnt/c/)